# ERROR ReferenceError: M is not defined //Materialize//

Tags: angular, npm, materialize

**Hi guys im having issues using toast animation... thats what I did:**

there is what i get in console

> ERROR ReferenceError: M is not defined
> addEmployee employees.component.ts:28
> RxJS 11
> Angular 16
> RxJS 16
> addEmployee employees.component.ts:25
> EmployeesComponent_Template_form_ngSubmit_5_listener employees.component.html:6
> Angular 3
> RxJS 5
> Angular 30
> EmployeesComponent_Template employees.component.html:6
> Angular 30
> ts main.ts:11
> Webpack 6 core.js:4197
> Angular 4
> RxJS 5
> Angular 20
> RxJS 12
> Angular 16
> RxJS 16
> addEmployee employees.component.ts:25
> EmployeesComponent_Template_form_ngSubmit_5_listener employees.component.html:6
> Angular 3
> __tryOrUnsub RxJS

Im using MEAN with materialize and I install it by npm install --save ngx-materialize

There is my Angular.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "frontend": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/frontend",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css",
              "node_modules/@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.min.css"
              
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "frontend:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "frontend:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "frontend:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "frontend:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "frontend:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }},
  "defaultProject": "frontend"
}
```

My index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Frontend</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

and my main component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { EmployeeService } from '../../services/employee.service'
import { Employee } from 'src/app/models/employee';

declare var M:any;


@Component({
  selector: 'app-employees',
  templateUrl: './employees.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employees.component.css'],
  providers: [EmployeeService]
})
export class EmployeesComponent implements OnInit {


  constructor(public employeeService: EmployeeService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  addEmployee(form: NgForm) {
    this.employeeService.postEmployee(form.value)
    .subscribe (res => {
      console.log(res)
      this.resetForm(form);
      M.toast({html: 'Bien guardao esta puto'});
    });
  }

  resetForm(form?: NgForm) {
    if (form){    //si existe pasa esto
      form.reset();
        this.employeeService.selectedEmployee = new Employee ();
    }


  }
}
```

thnx 4 all

Answer (score 0):

install materialize using npm

```
npm install materialize-css --save
```

Open angular.json file & add below styles & scripts.

```
styles: [
./node_modules/materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.css,
],
scripts: [
./node_modules/materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.js
]
```

then after

```
ng serve
```

this one solved my problem.